# In a Preemptive OS is it proper to use a Mutex or Semaphore between functions in the same task?

Tags: rtos

I am using an RTOS. The main program is only running two tasks besides the Idle Task.

Is it good coding practice to use a semaphore or mutex only between separate tasks? Or also between functions on the same task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mutex accessed *only* in a single thread serves no purpose - a lock attempt will always succeed because no other thread will have locked it.  If the mutex lock is nested - i.e. locked more than once before unlocking, it will also have no effect other then incrementing the mutex's internal counter.

There is an argument perhaps in using a mutex to protect a resource within code that may *later* under maintenance be accessed in multiple threads; but until that happens the mutex has no effect other than the consumption of CPU cycles.

---

The behaviour of a semaphore in this scenario is more complex, but the purpose of a semaphore is synchronisation and signalling *between* tasks, and so serves little purpose within a single thread that could not be implemented less expensively with a simple counter or flag.

In this scenario a semaphore is less benign than a mutex; critically a semaphore *will* block if an attempt is made to take it before it has been given; so the task will block (stop running) if the code attempts to take the semaphore when it is empty.  If the semaphore has a timeout the behaviour will be that of a rather elaborate conditional delay, if it has no timeout, the task will just stop and never resume, and if the timeout is zero, nothing will happen.

So in a single thread, depending on the state of the semaphore and the timeout used, it will either behave as a *task-suspend*, *task-delay* or *no-operation*. Using a semaphore to achieve either of these is perhaps an unnecessary obfuscation since any RTOS will have APIs to achieve task suspend and delay directly.

Comment: So a pre-emptive RTOS that uses DMA and is interrupt driven will still not need a mutex to protect that resource so long as that resource is only used inside that task?

I have a CLI written that is accessing the port externally. Once the data is received, it is processed by my functions. Are you saying that since this task is the only receiving task that it doesn't need a mutex?

Comment: I am not going to advise on a specific application from a vague description; but a mutex specifically prevents one task from _concurrently_ accessing a resource locked by another - by definition it has no effect if only ever locked and unlocked by one task.  However there may still be concurrency between the DMA transfer, the interrupt and a thread; but a mutex cannot be used in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're using the mutex or semaphore for.  What is its purpose?  And then consider whether it is necessary within the context of a single task.

A mutex is typically used to protect a resource from being accessed simultaneously by things that use the resource asynchronously.  Here, "asynchronously" means the things using the resource are not synchronized and may attempt to use the resource simultaneously.  Now, can a single task access the resource simultaneously from two different functions?  No, because a single task can only execute one function at a time.  Different functions in a single task are already synchronized by virtue of the task executing only one function at a time.  So I would say that a mutex does not provide any benefit when it is used by only one task.

Semaphores have other applications beyond that of a mutex, such as signalling an event.  I suppose there may be some applications in which using a semaphore that is accessed by only one task makes sense. But you haven't described your application so I'll leave it to you to consider for yourself.

Comment: Hello, I already accepted the answer above but I do see your point. 

Mutexes are for resources, semaphores are for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that they are mainly used for inter-task communications / synchronization / control of access to resources, so in the main they are used between tasks rather than in the same task.

There could be scenario's where this is not the case but I cannot really think of any at the moment.

Personally I think that it is best that a task only has one point of suspension in it, be it a putting or receiving something from a queue, waiting for a mutex or semaphore etc. There are situations where this is not always the case but it does make debugging much easier.

Comment: Hello, I already accepted the answer above but I do see your point. I think what you are getting at is that if a task has the need for more than one mutex, it should be split up into different tasks? Yes?